# Click event implementation for HeaderView

Tags: android

I have a navigation drawer. I've successfully populated `ListView` items programatically and assigned click listeners to it. 
The problem occurs when I add an item in the list using `headerView` function. I'm adding it like this

```
View headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, null);
((ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon)).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage));
((TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName)).setText("Text");
mDrawerList.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

Now, technically the `headerview` element should execute on `position` 0 in the following code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment3();
            break;
    }
}
```

But the last element's case is not working and gives an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. 
I'm creating `ListView` items this way:

```
ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[3];
drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_speedometer, mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[0]);
drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_place, mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[1]);
drawerItem[2] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_price, mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[2]);
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I make a click event that works for `HeaderView` as well as last `ListView` item?

PS: newbie alert!

Comment: Just implement headerView click event individually and outside the listview scope. Like, headerView.setonClickListener(this);

Comment: Ahan. A little confused about what you meant by "outside the listview scope"?

Comment: I meant don't write your headerView code inside onItemClick, just implement headerView.onClickListener individually.

Comment: Let me try and implement that.

Comment: @pratik I did what you suggested and now I'm getting a strange response. Please check my comment below Jithu's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Implement separate click listener for headderview like this

```
View headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, null);
((ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon)).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage));
((TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName)).setText("Text");
mDrawerList.addHeaderView(headerView);
headerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // code to execute
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did that. Now a strange thing happened. On clicking the 2nd item on the list, it executes case 1st item in the list, it executes `case 2`, and clicking 2nd item in the list executes `case 3`. :|

Comment: Try using a toast and display message in getView() as well as in headder.click(), and see which is showing, you can check with logcat also.

Comment: I did use a toast in `OnClick` and the toast is working correctly for the headerview. In the `switch` `case` scenario, I am loading a `fragment` in each cases so if it worked, it would launched a fragment. But it didn't.

Comment: if the toast shows correct position in the getView() and correctly in headder.click(), tyhen the problem might be with your fragment loading. use a function write globaly in the class and call the same. Some times it helps you.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on this please? Would really appreciate if you could also include relevant code. Thanks!

Comment: The rest of the code to show fragment is with you right!! if you past it here, I will try to check the issue. if you want, you can mail me: jithusidhardhan@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Jithu. I'd rather put the code here as the solution might help others in the future too. 
Please check my updated question for the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59718/discussion-between-basit-saeed-and-jithu).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you add a headerview or a footerview to the ListView, the Android system handles it as a child internally. But to the developer, the first item(0th position) is the listview's first item(0th position). There is a different class in Android HeaderListViewAdapter.

Comment: So what you mean to say is that despite adding a headerview, the ListView's furst item would be on 0th position?

Comment: Yeah... That is what am saying

Comment: But that's not how the app's behaving. When I click on the first list view item, `case` in place for `position` 1 gets executed instead of `position` 0